# Rendering issue with Mathjax-Latex on wordpress with twenty fourteen theme

Tags: wordpress, mathjax

I'm running my website http://www.mathcounterexamples.net with WordPress 4.1 and Mathjax-Latex plug-in 1.1.3. Since around a week, the rendering on my iPad or my Android Nexus 5 is wrong in horizontal views. In particular the website view is no more adapted to the width of the device. It is schrinked.

When I deactivate Mathjax-Latex plug-in, everything is fine. I have not change any options of Mathjax-Latex.

Do you have a clue of what can be wrong?

Thanks, Jean-Pierre.